# What is the general relationship between L.S.A. CI and the exact CI in the sign test?

Tags: confidence-interval, nonparametric, wilcoxon-signed-rank

We know that we can use the large sample approximation in calculating the confident interval of the median(location) of the sample distribution in the Fisher's sign test. We can, at the same time, obtain an exact confident interval using the binomial distribution.

1) What is the general relationship between the $CI_{LSA}$ and $CI_{exact}$? Is it always true that $CI_{LSA}\subset CI_{exact}$?

2) What is the general relationship between the $CI_{LSA}$ and $CI_{exact}$ in the situation of Wilcoxon Sign-rank test?

Note: L.S.A. means Large Sample Approximation.
I think 1) is generally true as long as the CI is from a 2-sided test, while if we just want a confident bound, the bound may be more conservative.